# Convert all HTML Links to another URL with HTML and Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying get all HTML links in a website's body section within a string and replace them to another link.

Tried something like this but did not work:

```js
var search = "https://www.cloudflare.com/5xx-error-landing?utm_source=error_footer";
var replacement = "https://example.com/";

document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.split(search).join(replacement)
```

Where "https://www.cloudflare.com/5xx-error-landing?utm_source=error_footer" is the link I want to replace and "https://example.com/" is the link that I want to replace with.

Comment: Is it only that one specific link you want to change within the entire page?

Answer (score 5):

How about this:

```
$("[href='your link']").attr("href","new link");
```

Comment: the question is about only JavaScript I guess

Comment: @KoushikChatterjee sorry but tagged by jquery

Comment: @daremachine, O yeah.. haha :)

Comment: Edited and reduced the `==`, now just using a css selector

Comment: so, is `.each` is required here at all? isn't `$("[href='your link']").attr("href","new link")` is enough?

Comment: any getter will return you the value of first element, but any setter will set it to all the elements that matches the selector, because you are doing against that. just try it out :)

Comment: @NirTzezana thanks for the edit, its a more optimized answer now. Looks good :) thums up ^

Answer (score 0):

```
$('body').find('a').each(function(){
    $(this).attr('href','your_new_link');
});
```

or for different href:

```
$('body').find('a').each(function(){
    var ahref = $(this).attr('href');
    if ( ahref == 'your_old_link') {  /// or ahref.indexOf("your_old_link") >= 0
         $(this).attr('href','your_new_link_1');
    }else{
         $(this).attr('href','your_new_link_2');
    }

});
```

Comment: its not correct because ahref is string .. you can not call .attr because is not jquery Object ... you tried yourself?

Comment: yes now its correct. $(this) is good but for replace and nested is it hell, I like using store that into variable like this https://jsfiddle.net/rqxdLp88/

Answer (score 0):

Just use

```
  $("body a[href='https://www.cloudflare.com']").attr("href","https://example.com/");
```

Comment: this is bad because replace ALL links but OP wants to replace only specific links

Comment: is `.each` is required here?

Comment: any getter will return you the value of first element, but any setter will set it to all the elements that matches the selector, because you are doing against that. just try it out :

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution with plain javascript as per your question

```
document.querySelectorAll("[href='" + search + "']").forEach(function(el){
    el.href = replacement );
});
```

If you want to use jQuery, as you tagged, follow the answer of Nir Tzezana